# Difference between algebraic and etale K-theory

Tags: etale-cohomology, algebraic-k-theory

Due to the Quillen-Lichtenbaum conjecture (now proven by Rost, Voevodsky, and Weibel), the map $K_\ast(X,\mathbb{Z}/n)\rightarrow K_\ast^{et}(X,\mathbb{Z}/n)$ from algebraic K-theory to etale K-theory is an isomorphism when $\ast$ is at least the mod $n$ etale cohomological dimension of $X$. (I think $X$ is a smooth scheme of finite type over a field which contains $1/n$.) In fact, we know from Thomason that $K_\ast^{et}$ can be obtained from $K_\ast$ by inverting a Bott element.

How can we measure the difference between $K_\ast$ and $K_\ast^{et}$? Since it is all concentrated within the etale cohomological dimension of $X$, I would guess the difference would look something like etale cohomology. Is there a long exact sequence?

Comment: The Quillen-Lichtenbaum conjecture is a consequence of the Bloch-Kato conjecture plus the motivic spectral sequence. That is to say, there is a spectral sequence converging to the fiber of $K\to K^{ét}$ whose $E_2$-page is the difference between étale and motivic cohomology. Measuring said difference is probably going to be very hard.